# c++, cannot instantiate abstract class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class called Enemy and another one called groundenemy1. I keep getting the same error cannot "instantiate abstract class", These are my two classes, I searched all over the internet but I couldn't fix it. I hope someone can help me.`

```
#pragma once
#include "Vector2f.h"
#include "CollisionManager.h"
class Enemy
{
public:
    Enemy(CollisionManager &collmanager);
    virtual ~Enemy();
    void Move(Vector2f move);
    void Update(float elapsedsec);
    virtual void Draw() =0;
protected:
    bool m_Jump;
    Rectf m_Shape;
    Vector2f m_Velocity,m_InputVelocity;
    CollisionManager m_CollManager;
    float m_Jumpspeed, m_Acceleration,m_JumpCooldown,m_WalkSpeed;
};

class GroundEnemie1 :public Enemy
{
public:
    GroundEnemie1(CollisionManager &collmanager,Sprite &sprite,Rectf shape);
    virtual ~GroundEnemie1();
    void Draw() override;
protected:
    Sprite m_Sprite;
};
```

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: `Enemy` cannot be instantiate since it has the function `virtual void Draw() = 0`, but you can definitely instantiate `GroundEnemie1`

Comment: `virtual void Draw() =0;` <-- define this method.

Comment: where is your main? Anyway, probably your problem is that `Draw()` method is not declared `virtual` in you `GroundEnemie1` class...

Comment: @SimoV8 I don't think he needs to declare `virtual` for the `Draw()` function in `GroundEnemie1`

Comment: I think we might need to see your implementations of the classes as well

Comment: I'm going to guess the error comes from a container. You can store "Enemy*" pointers, but the actual objects have different sizes, so for example a vector<Enemy> won't work.  One of the reasons is that vector has to be able to instantiate default objects, and it can't make a default Enemy, because it is abstract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't declare an object from an abstract class

because of the `virtual void Draw() = 0` function your Enemy class is an abstract class but you can instantiate an object GroundEnemie1

to understand easily

your GroundEnemie1 class can be called Dog, there is also a Cat class , a Fish class. All these classes inherites from Animal (Enemy for you).
You can't directly instantiate an Animal, you have to be more accurate, you instiate a Dog, a Cat, a Fish, depending what you need